# Permissions issue on opening a file - Perl, CGI

Tags: perl, cgi

I've been trying to create a log file for an application, using Perl and CGI in an Apache server. For this reason the script needs to keep a log file, which must be opened when the script starts. From the logs I get: `Unable to open the file: Permission denied at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/generate_logs.cgi`, and the script goes as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI qw(:standard);
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";
...
open (my $logs, ">", "/path/to/directory/logs.txt") || die "Unable to open the file: $!";
...
```

I've been trying to use non-root paths for the `.txt` log file, like `~/Desktop`, but still the script can't create/open log the file. Don't hesitate to ask me if you need more information. Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the UID:GID of the file itself, and what is the name of the user who's acting as the web server?

Comment: @stevieb, maybe I'm wrong, but isn't the file supposed to be created if it doesn't exist when the script tries to open it?

Comment: So what's your question? As the error says, the user+group as which the script runs doesn't have permission to create a file in `/path/to/directory`. Either configure apache to use a different user+group, or change the permissions so that the existing user+group can access the directory and create the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Apache web server typically runs as a separate user on your system.  Your `~/Desktop` directory will be specific to *YOUR* user.  Any directory Apache writes to will need to be writable by the Apache user.

To find what username Apache is operating under, check your config file.  This might have defaulted to `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. You will probably find a line in that file with the [`User` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_unixd.html#user).  It's probably set to user `apache`.

Apache already has a log directory.  Usually it's `/var/log/httpd`.  Perhaps try writing your log there.

Please note, the sample code you provided is very problematic.  Each time your CGI script is run, your log file will be erased and overwritten.  If it's run with concurrent users, you'll have even bigger problems.  Two threads trying to write the same file, locking issues, etc.  You may want to take a look at [`CGI::Log`](http://search.cpan.org/~jmoore/CGI-Log-1.00/Log.pm) for something more functional.

Comment: As I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 I couldn't find the file you told me, because the global configuration is in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. But I finally made it work by setting Apache the permissions to write in the folder I've selected, as you told me. Thanks!